# Missing Font Awesome icons in iTextSharp pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, vue.js, itext, font-awesome

I am trying to take HTML content and convert it to PDF using iTextSharp. Everything is working well except that the font-awesome icons do not appear in the resultant PDF.

My .NET MVC application is written in C# and utilizes Font Awesome Free 5.0.12 (using [Web Fonts with CSS](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css) method), iTextSharp 5.5.13 along with itextsharp.xmlworker, and Vue.js framework.

When the "Print" button gets clicked from the browser, a vue.js method gets called that takes the contents of the HTML to be converted (which is contained in a hidden div) and posts it to the appropriate controller method (and in turn takes the response data and loads it):

```
createPDF: function () {
    commonEventBus.$emit("show-loading-overlay", "Loading");

    var document = $("#printSummary");
    var model = {
        HtmlData: document.html()
    }
    return this.$http.post(commonApp.root + "PDF/Export", model, { responseType: "blob" })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // for IE
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(response.bodyBlob);
                commonEventBus.$emit("hide-overlay");
            }
            else {
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(response.bodyBlob);
                window.open(fileURL);
                commonEventBus.$emit("hide-overlay");
            }
        });
},
```

The Export method in the PDFController looks as such:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Export(HtmlViewModel model)
{
    var generator = new PDFGenerator();
    return File(generator.Generate(model), "application/pdf", "Confirmation" + DateTime.Now + ".pdf");
}
```

And the Generate method in the PDFGenerator class looks like this:

```
public byte[] Generate(HtmlViewModel html)
{
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["br"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["input"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["hr"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["img"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
    doc.LoadHtml(html.HtmlData);
    html.HtmlData = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

    byte[] bytesArray = null;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 40, 40))
        {
            using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms))
            {
                document.Open();
                using (var strReader = new StringReader(html.HtmlData))
                {
                    //Set factories
                    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
                    htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

                    //Set css
                    ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);

                    //Register a single font
                    cssResolver.AddCssFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/bootstrap.css"), true);
                    cssResolver.AddCssFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/app/print.css"), true);

                    //Export
                    IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));
                    var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
                    var xmlParse = new XMLParser(true, worker);
                    xmlParse.Parse(strReader);
                    xmlParse.Flush();
                }
                document.Close();
            }
        }
        bytesArray = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return bytesArray;
}
```

Any idea how to get the Font Awesome icons to show up? For instance, I have something like this in the HTML code that gets converted and it disappears in the PDF:

```
<i class="fas fa-1x fa-shopping-cart"></i> Print Order
```

I have also tried to use the unicode value instead but with no luck either:

```
<i class="fas">&#xf07a;</i> Print Order
```

Comment: It is likely that the iText processor is not handling before:: . If you add JS to insert the icons online as the sample below does they would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText has **zero** knowledge of Font Awesome, so you need to do a little more work. Following is simple tested/working example.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.fas { font-family: FontAwesome; color:green; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<i class='fas'>&#xf07a;</i> Print Order
</body></html>
```

Parsing code - note inline comments:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(OUTPUT_FILE, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();

        var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
        // path to fontawesome.css
        cssResolver.AddCssFile(CSS_PATH, true);

        // question missing this part - REGISTER the font(s)
        var fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
        // may need to add other web-fonts-with-css\webfonts\*.ttf depending on needs 
        fontProvider.Register(Path.Combine(FONT_PATH, "fa-solid-900.ttf"), "FontAwesome");
        var cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);

        var htmlPipelineContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
        htmlPipelineContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        var pdfWriterPipeline = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
        var htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlPipelineContext, pdfWriterPipeline);
        var cssResolverPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(
            cssResolver, htmlPipeline
        );

        var worker = new XMLWorker(cssResolverPipeline, true);
        var parser = new XMLParser(worker);
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(XHTML))
        {
            parser.Parse(stringReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

A couple of notes:

- Didn't try that hard, but used the Font Awesome specific unicode. Empty Html node with Font Awesome specific classes didn't work for me.
- The iText CSS parser is pretty basic, so try to keep things simple like in the HTML snippet above.

Comment: Buried in this library JS is Javascript that copies the pseudo before elements in Font Aweome to online before printing http://cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.GlyphIcons